# import 'kotlinx.android.synthetic' does not work

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a project mainly written in Java, and I just need Kotlin for a few fragments.

And, I noticed that the import 'kotlinx.android.synthetic' does not work.

How to allow this import (for a project 99% written in Java) ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you have the following in your app-level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Additionally, if you actually are writing

```kotlin
import 'kotlinx.android.synthetic'
```

then you should remove the quotes, as imports are not quoted in Kotlin:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.android.synthetic
```

And note also that you'll *typically* want to be importing some subpackage, such as:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

---

All of that said, the Kotlin extensions for synthetic views aren't really recommended these days (you might note that they're even missing from [JetBrains's "Kotlin for Android" page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/android-overview.html)).  Take a look at [this comment from a Google Developer Advocate](https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/efdvpkg/) for more information on why.